# I cannot disable multiple fields using Jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button, field

I have two radio buttons. When users click yes, all the fields can be entered. When the user clicks the "no" radio button all the fields disable.

The problem: I'm using jquery but it is only allowing me to disable one field at a time. Is there a work around. Heres the code.

Code below: 
http://jsfiddle.net/moehammoud/YBe64/1/

It works for the first field but when I start to try and make the radio button affect more than one field it doesn't apply at all

```
$(function(){
$("#test-y, #test-n").change(function(){
    $("#field1", "#field2").attr("disabled",true);
    if($("#test-y").is(":checked")){
        $("#field1", "#field2").removeAttr("disabled");
        $( "#field1", "#field2").css("background-color","#CCCECA");
    }
    else if($("#test-n").is(":checked")){
        $("#field1", "#field2").attr("disabled");
        $( "#field1", "#field2" ).css("background-color","gray");
    }
});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/moehammoud/PM69z/1/

I want it to work for 8 fields and a submit button.

This code is the easiest for me to understand so far. If anyone knows a fix to this particular level of code, would be awesome, any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Thanks all.
Moe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have incorrect syntax for selecting multiple elements in jQuery. If you want to select `#field1` and `#field2`, the syntax is:

```
$("#field1, #field2")
```

When you write `$("#field1", "#field2")`, it's equivalent to `$("#field2").find("#field1")`.

If you're repeatedly selecting several IDs like this you probably should give them a class so you can just specify the class name in the selector, rather than listing all the IDs separately.

Comment: Thanks heaps!! that worked a treat. The form is up and live now. Thanks again! :D

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
$(function () {
    $("#test-y, #test-n").change(function () {
        var checked = $("#test-y").is(":checked");
        $("#field1, #field2").prop("disabled", checked).css("background-color", checked ? "#CCCECA" : "gray");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hwpz8/)

Problems

- use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set the disabled state instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) - [prop vs attr](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc)
- You need to use [multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) to select different elements
- You used the id `field1` twice instead of field1 and field2

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#field1", "#field2").attr("disabled" , true);
```

Isn't the correct way for your wish. I suggest you make use of classes and/or the name attribute. You can also call the function on load by

```
$("input[name=test]").change();
```

That makes less code.

```
$(function() {
$("input[name=test]").change(function() {
    if($("#test-y").prop("checked") == true) {
        $(".field").prop("disabled" , false);
        $(".field").css("background-color" , "#ccceca");
        }
    else {
        $(".field").prop("disabled" , true);
        $(".field").css("background-color" , "gray");
        }
    });
$("input[name=test]").change();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dinizworld/Ckz8c/